# React testing library typescript. ES6 modules breaking test cases

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, react-testing-library, babel-jest

i have a small project on React + Typescript + Mui v5. It is a rather small application with an out of the box CRA setup.

I am relatively new to unit and integration testing, willing to use what CRA has provided me with:

```
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.0.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.2.1",
    "@types/jest": "^27.0.1",
```

However, i am not able to launch my test-cases with React-testing-library, as it fails with the following message:

```
    SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

    > 1 | import styled from '@mui/material/styles/styled';
        | ^
      2 | import { Box } from '@mui/material';
      3 |
      4 | export const Wrapper = styled(Box)(({ theme }) => ({
```

The code that throws is found in the MUI library itself inside node_modules folder, yet it somehow manages to break my tests. Do you have any clue what could fix this error ? I have read the whole internet of hints and ideas on this topic, and yet nothing has worked so far for me. I have tried modifiying my jest.config/babel.config in a dozen of ways, yet the error will not go away.

P.S. This only happens with tests that i write for components that use the MUI styling engine. For the ones that do not use it everything seems fine on this matter, but there is another one :).

The second issue that i encountered is from the fact that i use absolute imports in my project.

```
import {Button} from 'components';
```

And RTL and Jest fail to render components that make use of such imported components with the message: "Cannot find module 'components'". I also need a way to let Jest know how to import those.

Por favore, can someone help ? Maybe you had similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

This should fix it:

`import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles';`

You should import `styled` from `@mui/material/styles` instead of importing directly from `node_modules`. Otherwise you'll get all sorts of import issues.

I would guess what happened it that you used intellisense to import via your IDE, and it incorrectly picked `'@mui/material/styles/styled'` instead of `'@mui/material/styles'`